# How to deploy SSR react app with latest react18 streaming?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, streaming, server-side-rendering, serverless

The latest version of react(18) comes with SSR streaming which allows to selectively render/hydrate elements.

The deployment of such application could be done in EC2 instances.

What about serverless options like (Lambda, Fargate...) ?